# Event binding on file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Is there a way to bind an event when a user selects a file to upload and clicks on "open", I want to trigger the event when the user has clicked on open.

[image]

Comment: the change event of the field should trigger in that occasion

Comment: could be duplicated. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096335/jquery-start-a-function-after-open-button-from-input-file-is-pressed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that scenario, the `change` event will be fired.

If you have this HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

Then use this JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("fileInput").onchange = function () {
        // this.value
    };
};
```

(with the option of using `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` instead of setting the `onclick` property)

Inside the handler, you can use `this.value` to get the file selected.

Of course, with jQuery, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fileInput").on("change", function () {
        // this.value OR $(this).val()
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** The `window.onload` and `$(document).ready` handlers are used to make sure the element is available. Of course, this event can occur much later than actually necessary, since they wait for all elements on the page to be ready (and `window.onload` waits even longer for things like images to be loaded). An option is to bind the `onchange` handler immediately after the element on the page or at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: The `window`'s `onload` wrapper is rather unnecessary if the script is placed in the end of the page/after the input element. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté True, but I don't like doing that and it's basically the same thing as being at the end of the body (a little different for `window.onload`, but still). And I don't exactly find that important related to this question. Nonetheless, I'll add a little tidbit about it in the answer. Thanks :)