# How to upload image when click on upload button in vueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to uploading image using Vuejs, when I clicked on upload button, it will brow the image and uploaded. I tried following code bellow.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" />
<button type="button">upload</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {   
        image: ''
    }
);
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything. You just created a file input , button and vue instance that's it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975254/392102

Comment: http://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/